# Correct way to pass a POJO (no volatile fields,synchronized methods) between multiple threads and assure visibility of changes?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I've found a lot of questions & answers related to visibility, synchronization and threading but none that seemed to cover my particular use-case (or maybe I just suck at searching ;-) so I'll ask a new question and hope some generous soul will enlighten me :)

My question is: Given the code below, will accessing fields of the WorkItem items in the main thread properly reflect any changes done to them by the threadpool worker threads ?

My suspicion is "NO" , as this feel similar to passing an array of some values around and just synchronizing on the array reference but not on individual elements ... there must be a reason why classes like AtomicReferenceArray exist in the JDK and why they use getVolatile()/setVolatile() when accessing individual elements.

```
package com.voipfuture.voipmng.monitoring;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class IsThisThreadSafe
{
    public static class WorkItem { public String field1,field2; /* etc. */ }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        final List<WorkItem> items = List.of(new WorkItem(), new WorkItem());

        final CountDownLatch finished = new CountDownLatch(items.size());
        for (WorkItem item : items)
        {
            service.submit(() ->
            {
                try
                {
                    synchronized (item)
                    {
                        // mutate object
                        item.field1 = "test";
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    finished.countDown();
                }
            });
        }
        finished.await();

        for (WorkItem item : items)
        {
            // will this make sure all changes done inside
            // threadpool worker threads are visible here ?
            synchronized (item)
            {
                // do stuff with work item
                System.out.println(item.field1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend using standard Java code formatting; in this case, it would reduce the vertical size of your code by about 25%. Also, if you're going to handle multithreading, I strongly recommend learning about the _happens-before_ concept (specifically, the operations on a POJO happen-before anything else in the same thread, and the latch countdown happens-before the await).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Given the code below, will accessing fields of the WorkItem items in the main thread properly reflect any changes done to them by the threadpool worker threads ?

The answer is actually yes, you will. There are two reasons you ensure vsibility.

1. `synchronized(item)`: Let's say you do not have the `CountDownLatch` (more on that next) but you just have the `synchronized(item)` in there. Since you are synchronizing on both reads and writes ***of the same instance***, then the reading thread will see changes that happen prior to the writes. **However**, if the writes hadn't occurred then you will not see the value `test` you'd just see `null`. So, even though it guarantees memory visibility, it doesn't guarantee a program order.
2. `finished.await();` Let's now assume you remove `synchronized(item)`. If all you had was `finished.countDown()` and `finished.await()` you are guaranteeing any updates that happen prior to the continuation of `await` will now be visible after exiting `await`. So just using the `CountDownLatch` you are giving your program both memory visibility and a concurrent program order.

From [CountDownLatch javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

> Memory consistency effects: Until the count reaches zero, actions in a thread prior to calling countDown() happen-before actions following a successful return from a corresponding await() in another thread.

Comment: Thank you, I missed the JavaDoc comment on the memory consistency of CountDownLatch.

Answer (score 0):

If all the access (both read and write) on a shared object is done in a synchronized block by all threads, then access is safe. A synchronized block adds a memory barrier so any modifications waiting to be written to the main memory are committed.